# AjaxControlToolkit not working after publish. ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

What I found the cause to be is that AjaxControlToolkit works when you have debug = "true" in the compilation tag of the web.config    the moment i put debug="false" the control no longer works.
Reading this article http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/11/Don_1920_t-run-production-ASP.NET-Applications-with-debug_3D001D20_true_1D20_-enabled.aspx
I see its not a good thing to leave the debug tag set to true, is there any way this can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a problem with the ajax control toolkit, try removing it and re-adding or create a new project copy your files over and install it from nuget

Comment: Don't think so, I used nugget to install the toolkit in the first, re adding the dll's also did not work. I am thinking its an inherent bug with the toolkit. Not 100% sure though. If I have time today will make a dummy project and see if I get the same behavior. Thanks though for your reply

Comment: Okay so I created a dummy application and it works perfectly, So my guess is you are correct, but it could be another dll in my website that could be causing this. Will try your approach of creating a whole new project

Comment: could be, reckon you got unlucky, it seemed t0 cause me all kinds on issues and putting it back together just seemed to work, ones of those mysteries

Comment: Okay So i moved everything to a new project - it still does not work just for kicks i ran IE in debug mode and I see its breaking on javascript "Object doesn't support this action ScriptResource.axd". My problem still persists - i will need to may be try this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1068317.aspx?Calendar+Extender+Error+in+ScriptResource+axd+line+1162